# Jackson serialize custom TreeNode object to return JSONObject

Tags: java, serialization, jackson, treenode

I have an Object like this :

```
public class TreeNodeLabel {

    TreeNodeLabel parent;
    List<TreeNodeLabel> children;
    Map<String, String> prop;
    String name;
}
```

I want to obtain JSONObject like this

```
"data": {
    "auth": {
      "myChallenges": "Visualiser vos défis",
      "myMessages": "Accéder à la messagerie",
      "myProfile": "Accéder à votre profil",
      "myGroup": "Accéder à vos groupes",
      "launchChallenge": "Lancer un défi",
      "login": {
        "login": "Me connecter",
        "label": "Connectez-vous",
        "loginLabel": "E-mail",
        "passwordLabel": "Mot de passe",
        "action": "Je me connecte",
        "sign": "M'inscrire",
        "facebook": "Facebook",
        "google": "Google",
        "lost": "Mot de passe oublié ?",
        "lostParam": "Hey {name}, déjà {passwordCount, number} {passwordCount, plural, one {mot de passe oublié} other {mots de passe oubliés}} ce mois ci !",
        "useSocialNetwork": "Utilisez vos réseaux sociaux pour vous connecter",
        "noAccount": "Je n'ai pas de compte",
        "errors": {
          "loginRequired": "Email requis",
          "loginFormat": "Format de l'email incorrect",
          "passwordRequired": "Mot de passe obligatoire",
          "passwordFormat": "Format invalide"
        }
      },
      "socialNetworkErrors": {
        "missingPermissions": "Vous devez partager votre email pour vous connecter avec votre compte Facebook.",
        "inProgress": "Une connexion via Google est déjà en cours.",
        "playServicesNotAvailable": "Les services Google Play ne sont pas installés ou pas à jour."
      }
    },
    "message": {
      "chatView": {
        "loadPreviousMessages": "Charger les messages précédents",
        "send": "Envoyer",
        "placeholder": "Ecrivez un message..."
      },
      "conversation": {
        "duration": "Il y a"
      }
    }
}
```

I tried with some different annotations like (@JsonManagedReference,@JsonIgnore,@JsonProperty)
but obtain JSON that contains objects named "children","prop" instead of property "name" for each children and list of prop under this

Comment: Not entirely sure, but did you serialize the right object? Where is all that data you've shown in the output coming from?

Comment: They come from a property file that I use before to create my tree

Answer (score 0):

You could add a method marked with @JsonValue to your TreeNodeLabel class that produces the structure you want.

e.g.

```
    @JsonValue
    public Map<String, Map<String, Object>> jsonValue() {
        Map<String, Map<String, Object>> values = new HashMap<>();
        Map<String, Object> propValues = new HashMap<>();
        propValues.putAll(prop);
        // add each of the children.
        for (TreeNodeLabel child : children) {
            propValues.putAll(child.jsonValue());
        }
        values.put(name, propValues);
        return values;
    }
```

If you want to deserialize too then you'll need to add a @JsonCreator.